# How do I get active unix domain sockets for a specific pid if I can't use lsof command?

Tags: socket, netstat

If I have no permission to use lsof, how do I get them for a process with pid already known? Thanks

I know `netstat -l -p` command print out active unix domain sockets, but it seems it's not updating ? after I closed the socket, it still shows up in netstat command  result.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: `netstat -lp` shows the listening (server) sockets. If that socket has been closed on the process(es), it can't show up in there. You may prefer `ss` to `netstat` as `netstat` gives at most one process per socket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux you can look through the `/proc` filesystem specifically for a given PID under `/proc/<pid>/fd`. All the file descriptors (fd) are listed there per process.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l /proc/27634/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:09 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:09 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:10 10 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:10 12 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:10 13 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:09 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:09 3 -> socket:[430396]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:09 4 -> socket:[430437]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:09 5 -> pipe:[430440]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:10 6 -> pipe:[430440]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:10 7 -> socket:[430443]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:10 8 -> socket:[430444]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 17 20:10 9 -> socket:[430446]
```

Everything listed there as `socket:[....]` is a socket.

Comment: And to know if they're `unix`, `tcp`, `udp` or other sockets, you can try `grep -slw 430396 /proc/net/*` for instance.